# How to find the log-likelihood for this density?

Tags: statistics, log-likelihood

We let $(X,Y)$ be stochastic variables with values in $N × R$  determined by $ X = x $ being subtracted from one
Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda$
after which Y is subtracted from a gamma distribution with shape parameter x + 1 and scale parameter β, i.e. the simultaneous distribution of (X, Y) has the density:
$$f_{(\lambda,\beta)}(x,y)=\frac{\lambda^{x}}{x!}e^{-\lambda}\frac{y^{x}}{\beta^{x+1}x!}e^{-\frac{y}{\beta}}$$
with respect to m×$\nu$ where m is the count measure on $N_0$ and ν is the standard lebesgue measure on $R^+$.
I'm not totally sure how to find the log-likelihood function. I have in the solution that: $$l_{n}(\lambda,\beta)=log \lambda \sum_i X_i-log \beta \sum_i X_i-\sum_I Y_i/\beta-n \lambda-n log \beta$$.
But how to find it? I have seen some easy example but not that diffucult. Can anyone help me with a guide and some tricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy. The trick is to eliminate any element not depending on the parameter thus your likelihood is

$$L \propto \lambda ^{\Sigma_i X_i}e^{-n \lambda}\beta^{-\Sigma_i(X_i+1)}e^{-\Sigma_i Y_i/\beta}$$

Now take the log and find the solution

$$l=\log\lambda\Sigma_i X_i-n\lambda-\Sigma_i(X_i+1)\log\beta-\frac{\Sigma_i Y_i}{\beta}$$

Comment: Aha you just eliminate any element not depending on the parameter $\lambda$ and $\beta$ and then sum it? But why do $e^{\frac{\lambda}{\beta}}$ be to $e^{-\sum_i \frac{\lambda}{\beta}}$? why the minus?

Comment: @Lifeni : the minus is a clear typo in your density. It cannot be $e^{y/\beta}$ because it would non converge

Comment: Yes it was a typo. Thank you that makes sense :-)